# Trying to get my "loading..." div to work with MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have the following code:

```
<div id="loading" style="display:none; color:red">
Loading.....
</div>

<a  OnClick ="return ShowPanel();"  href="@Url.Action("DownloadReport", "Downloader", new {ReportId = id}, null)">download report<</a>

<script type ="text/javascript">
 function ShowPanel()
 {
    var pnl = document.getElementById("loading");
    pnl.style.display='block';
    return true;
 }
</script>
```

In my controller I return the document via a popup download window:

```
return myDocument.ExportAsActionResult("myDoc.docx", FormatType.Docx, HttpContext.ApplicationInstance.Response, HttpContentDisposition.Attachment);
```

Thus the page does not refresh in itself, so I cannot rely on #loading going back to "display.none" on refresh. Thus it stays with "Loading...."

How can I remove "Loading....." when the Download doc popup appears.? I will probably swap loading for a spinner when I can successfully make this div invisible when download window appears.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT

```
<a href = "#" onclick="callDownloadReport(1059);" >download report</a>

<script type ="text/javascript">
function callDownloadReport(ReportId) {
$.ajax({
    url: 'Downloader/DownloadReport',
    data: { ReportId: ReportId },
    success: function () {
        var pnl = document.getElementById("loading");
        pnl.style.display = 'none';
    },
    error: function () {
    }
});
}
</script>
```

EDIT2

What the url should be:

```
http://localhost:2000/Downloader/DownloadReport?ReportId=1059
```

What the Ajax function is producing:

```
http://localhost:2000/Section/Query/1059/Downloader/DownloadReport?ReportId=1059
```

FINAL EDIT:

I ended up using Ajax.Actionlink. However "Return File" type commands will not work with Ajax. You need to use an iframe:

```
<script type ="text/javascript">


$(function () {
    $('#DownloadDoc').click(function () {

        $('#Document').html(
            $('<iframe/>', {
                src: this.href,
                width: '1px',
                height: '1px'
            })
        );
        return true;
    });
});

</script>
```

I have found Ajax.Actionlink to be most helpful in the context of MVC asp.net. If you want to wrap an anchor tag around other content then use the resultant HTML directly ie:

```
<a data-ajax="true" data-ajax-begin="ajaxStart" data-ajax-complete="ajaxStop" data-ajax-method="Get" href="@Url.Action("DownloadDoc", "Downloader", new {ReportId = Model.First().ReportId }, null)" id="DownloadDoc">
```

I am using "data-ajax-begin" and "data-ajax-complete" to show and hide the progress spinner. However I have notice that the timing can be out ie the browser spinner is still going and this download spinner has finished. There is a property called "LoadingElementId" which may be better. Need to test.

Hope the above helps someone.

Thanks for everybody's help.

Comment: Just inject your action URL into your ajax call...`url: "@Url.Action("DownloadReport", "Downloader" etc...)"`, then your action URL will be correct no matter what page you call it from

Comment: Thanks for this Charleh. Yes works great. However since I am returning a generated Word file, my download file popup no longer appears. You will see my "Return..." statement in my question...

Comment: Do you have code in the click handler for your link to show the pop-up? It looks like you are just calling the ajax load but haven't popped up the loader beforehand. Shouldn't `showPopup` appear before the ajax call?

Comment: Thanks for this. I have note written "ShowPopup". Is this the way to return the file, when using an Ajax load? If so what would it look like?

Comment: Can you clarify for me, are you expecting to see a browser pop-up asking you to save/open the file or are you expecting to see a pop-up within your html site that show's an ongoing download? I'm confused about what you want to show and what you are having trouble with?

Comment: If you want to copy the resulting content of a page into a pop-up window in the DOM you need to use either jQuery.load or handle the success function and replace the content of the pop-up window with the result of the Ajax call

Comment: E.g `$("#popupWindowDivId").html(data)` in your success function assuming you have called the first arg to success `data`

Comment: I ended up going with Ajax.ActionLink used in conjunction with an IFrame which you need to callback a "Return File". Ajax and Return file does not work on its own. Found this from the informative "Darin...."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a $.ajax() call to your action method on click of the link. In the Success callback of this ajax call, you can disable the "Loading..." div.

Let me know if you have trouble calling $.ajax().

UPDATE: 
Please modify your anchor tag like this.

```
<a href="#" onclick="callDownloadReport('@Model.ReportId');">download report</a>
```

And, modify your javascript like this.

```
function callDownloadReport(reportId) {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'Downloader/DownloadReport',
        data: { ReportId: reportId },
        success: function () {
            var pnl = document.getElementById("loading");
            pnl.style.display = 'none';
        },
        error: function () {
        }
    });
}
```

I have not tested this code but I'm sure you get a hang of what I'm trying to point here.

Comment: Thanks again, just checking. Quick question though with the "url" attribute. Usually when I use the razor @Html.Action method I get the full URL automatically including server name, however with your approach I cannot see how I would get the full url ie including the server name, if I need it?

Comment: How do I incorporate razor into this JQuery ie data: { ReportId: @(Model.First().ReportId) }, . This does not work incidentally.

Comment: You don't need to do that. It will consider "Download" as Controller and "DownloadReport" as Action and append it to the Referrer URL till the server name. This route will be specified in your Global.asax.

Comment: You can create a hidden field where you store the value of "ReportId" and then access it in javascript

Comment: Or would be better to pass it in as a argument to callDownloadReport. Sorry my JS/JQuery is a little weak at present, so an example of both these approaches would be hugely appreciated.

Comment: Getting no call to action at present, no browser "activity" wheel, just nothing. I have added my code to EDIT in my question.

Comment: My Edit has appeared all over the place. Aologies. Just check my EDIT to my question.

Comment: Please check in browser Network panel if the request is getting fired.

Comment: Ok, it is getting fired, but nothing happens. Just a process lasting 40ms... Usually takes much longer. I will just try without the ajax

Comment: You must be getting an error. Just put a debugger in your error callback method and check what is the error. You are absolutely on the verge of getting the solution. Don't give up now. :)

Comment: Ok, The problem is that the wrong URL is getting fired. See EDIT. Basically the original URL is getting added to rather than replaced by the real one. I think the # may be doing this.

Comment: You will see that the AJAX created URL cannot succeed since it is incorrect. I did see http://localhost:2000/Section/Query/1059# when hovering over the download link as opposed to #.

Comment: Just see that you url becomes proper. You can use ActionLink instead of directly using anchor tag.

Comment: I have now tested using the explicit http://localhost:2000...... URL value and this does seem to work ie there is a pause in the network monitor and then the process ends with a time for the process, however there is no download document dialogue. However if I open the URL in a new tab via network monitor it works fine, but I guess this is not via Ajax, it is manual.

Comment: OK, what would the ActionLink look like. Sorry for all the time this is taking up, I appreciate your efforts. We will get there.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49817/discussion-between-rks-and-samjolly)

Comment: Question concluded with my final answer in FINAL EDIT of my question. Thank you so much for your efforts.